# Transferring data through Prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I got an issue which I cant seem to understand why it happens.

> Ive created a class called "Apples" on a new Swife and called it
>   Apples.

```
class Apples { 
   var points = points()
   var appleName = String?
}
```

> constructed a struct called points to define the apple parameters

```
struct points {

  var taste = 0
  var smell = 0
  var texture = 0
  var color = 0


}
```

> and constructed a function to make new apples

```
func newApples(t:Int, s: Int, tex: Int, col: Int, appName = String)
{
  let newApple = Apples()
  newApple.points.taste = t
  newApple.points.smell = s
  newApple.points.texture = tex
  newApple.points.color = col
 newApple.appleName = appName
}
```

> and then I got 2 ViewControllers, 1 is AppleViewController, and the
>   2nd is ChoiceViewController.
>
> I called

```
let pinkLady = newApples(t: 5, s: 4, tex: 4, col: 5, appName = "Pink Lady")
```

> on the **AppleViewController**
>
> On the ChoiceViewController I got some UILabel Outlet(appleLabel)
>   which I want to change according to the Apple the user picked on the
>   1st AppleViewController
>
> the problem lies when I try to make a Prepare(for segue:) function

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let choiceVC = segue.destination as! ChoiceViewController  
        choiceVC.appleLabel.text = pinkLady.appleName
    }
```

> And in that last line of code lies the problem, When im running the
>   app and click the button with no line of code in (prepare for segue)
>   function  it performs the segue just fine,  but with it it calls 
>   "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"
>
> I tried all sort of syntax such as

```
 choiceVC.appleLabel.text = ((pinkLady.appleName)!)
 choiceVC.appleLabel.text = pinkLady.appleName?
 choiceVC.appleLabel.text = ("\(pinkLady.appleName?)")
```

> and then I tried to just put
>
> print((pinkLady.appleName)!)
>
> inside the prepare(for segue) function  and when it performed it
>   printed out to the console Pink Lady  with no problem. i really dont
>   know what im missing here.

Comment: your problem is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which means theres a nil somewhere it shouldnt be. set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue and go line by line until you find the nil.

Comment: I think the problem hapens because your appleLabel did not allocated in memory yet. Try to declate a var srting in choiseVC, and then in viewdidload func, assign it to uilabel's text

Comment: as I said, its calling nil on the line to change the appleLabel.text to 
pinkLady.appleName 
but when im printing the same value it does not return nil, it returns Pink Lady

Comment: How do I solve that Asike?
(**mentioning im fairly new to Swift)

Comment: I editted my comment above. I never use segues but it assumes that was the reason

Comment: Thanks alot, ill try that and see what I come up with !

Comment: And do not forget to tell us about your result

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much time I spent trying to decipher it.

I went to choiceVC and added 

var labels = String("BlaBla")

then went to ViewDidLoad and added

appleLabel.text = labels

and changed the line in the prepare for segue function to 

choiceVC.labels = pinkLady.appleName

Comment: No problem man. i recomend you not using massive storyboards with many viwcontollers in it, divide them in small parts with few or just one vc per storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because your `appleLabel` was not allocated in memory yet. Try to declare a var string in choiseVC, and then in viewdidload func, assign it to uilabel's text.

Answer (score 0):

First You are try it by entering static value like.

```
choiceVC.appleLabel.text = "This Is Apple"
```

using this static data you are not got any error thats means your code is correct. Problem is `pinkLady.appleName` found nil.

other wise use this code instead of segue code

```
let choiceVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChoiceViewController") as? ChoiceViewController
choiceVC.appleLabel.text = (pinkLady.appleName
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(choiceVC!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
let strPinkLady : String = pinkLady.appleName?
choiceVC.appleLabel.text = strPinkLady
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Make an object say pinkLadyInChoice, in ChoiceVC of type  Apples.
and pass pinkLady object to declared above, here pinkLadyInChoice, through prepareForSegue Method.
Then in ChoiceVC set text of labels by using object pinkLadyInChoice here.
```

From ApplesVC pass pinkLady object to ChoiceVC strPinkLady object

In choiceVC write the following :-

```
let strPinkLady : Apples 
choiceVC.appleLabel.text = strPinkLady.appleName
```